# Working with Hashes

Tags: python, ruby

I want to create a hash(dictionary) just like this: `dic = {2 => "ABC", 3 => "DEF"}`. In python the code looks like this:

```
text = "abcdef"  

for letter in text.lower():
    for group, number in dic.items(): 
        if letter in group:
```

For each letter in text de code looks for the same letter in the dictionary. How can I do this in ruby? Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you know how to declare a hash. What is your question?

Comment: I have this hash, I want enter with a letter and I want the number corresponding to the letter.

Ex: I enter letter C and the return will be 2

Comment: In both Python and Ruby I'd say your hash is reversed. You should be searching keys and returning values, instead of searching values and returning keys... but that's just how I think. Actually, I'd split the values into separate hash keys, and have each point to the same value so the lookup is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a direct translation of your code(which by the way does not match your description):

```
hash = {
  "abc" => 1,
  "def" => 2,
}

str = "abcdef"

str.downcase.each_char do |char|
  hash.each_pair do |key, val|
    puts val if key.include?(char)
  end
end


--output:--
1
1
1
2
2
2
```

However, that is O(n^2), which means it's inefficient.  You would probably be better off constructing a better hash:

```
hash = {
  "abc" => 1,
  "def" => 2,
}

new_hash = {}

hash.each_pair do |key, val|
  key.each_char do |char|
    new_hash[char] = val
  end
end

p new_hash

--output:--
{"a"=>1, "b"=>1, "c"=>1, "d"=>2, "e"=>2, "f"=>2}
```

With that code, you traverse the hash once to create the new hash, and the subsequent hash lookups are very efficient.  With your original code, you traverse the whole hash for every letter in the string.

Comment: +1, this is what I'd do. It's more efficient and would be a lot faster.

Comment: Thats exactly what I want!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2442149, But according to these five imbeciles: "squiguy, talonmies, sawa, Vin, soon" your question is not a real question.

Answer (score 0):

```
test = "abcdef"
dic = {2 => "ABC", 3 => "DEF"}
test.each_char { |s|
    dic.each { |key, val|
        puts key if val.include?(s.upcase)          
    }
}
```

Is it what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "abcdef"
hash = {2 => "ABC", 3 => "DEF"}
text.upcase.each_char do |c|
  puts hash.keys.find{|k| hash[k].include?(c.upcase)}
end
```

This outputs:

```
2
2
2
3
3
3
```

It seems you want a case-insensitive search, so I call `upcase` on both data sources.  If `text` is guaranteed to be lower-case or the Hash values are guaranteed to be upper-case, then one of those can be removed.  One benefit this has over the existing answers is that it only searches until it finds a matching value, which I think is what you want.  The search returns `nil` in case no matching value is found.